# H3 tag contents do not change on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I created a button using div tag. It is not actually a button but it is look like a button. Here I want to change the content of h3 tag to '>' this symbol when mouse is hover on it. How to do it?

I write code in javascript to change h3 contents but it will not show any effect? I don't know why?

```js
function change-content() {
  document.getElementById('button-name').innerHTML = ">";
}
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #6badf6;
}
#button-layout {
  background-color: #3b81cf;
  width: 100px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-left: 50%;
  margin-top: 25%;
}
#button-name {
  font-family: verdana;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 22px;
  padding-top: 11px;
}
#button-name:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="button-layout">
    <h3 id="button-name" onmouseover="change-content()">Submit</h3>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 12):

You can actually do this using pure CSS, no JS required, by adding attributes to the button containing the text you want for both the normal and hover states, and then setting the content of the `:after` pseudo to show this depending on `:hover`.

**This also maintains clear separation of concerns**, keeping content within your HTML and outside of your JS, meaning should you wish to change the value being displayed, you can simply reference the source markup directly.

```css
body {
    background-color: #6badf6;
}
#button-layout {
    background-color: #3b81cf;
    width: 100px;
    height: 40px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-left: 50%;
    margin-top: 25%;
}
#button-name {
    font-family: verdana;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 11px;
}
#button-name:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}
#button-name:after {
    content: attr(data-label);
}
#button-name:hover:after {
    content: attr(data-label-hover);
}
```

```html
<div id="button-layout">
  <h3 id="button-name" data-label="Submit" data-label-hover=">"></h3>
</div>
```

Concerning why your code currently isnt working, this has also been [answered in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29913388/404335), namely, your function name contains the invalid `-` character.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is in function declaration. define function with (_) like function change_content() it will work

Answer (score 0):

Your function name is invalid. The parser see that as a subtraction.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    body {
      background-color: #6badf6;
    }
    #button-layout {
      background-color: #3b81cf;
      width: 100px;
      height: 40px;
      border-radius: 10px;
      margin-left: 50%;
      margin-top: 25%;
    }
    #button-name {
      font-family: verdana;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: white;
      padding-left: 22px;
      padding-top: 11px;
    }
    #button-name:hover {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    function changeContent() {
      document.getElementById('button-name').innerHTML = ">";
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="button-layout">
    <h3 id="button-name" onmouseover="changeContent()">Submit</h3>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

change your function name see example

```
changecontent()
```